# rspec if giving a NoMethodError for Updating a User.field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Why does:

```
User.stuff_to_extract = 'boo'
```

work in the rails c

But in rspec it fails with this:

```
 Failure/Error: @user1.stuff_to_extract = 'XXXXXX'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `stuff_to_extract=' for #<User:0x105cd4e60>



require 'factory_girl'

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:fname) { |n| "fname#{n}" }
  f.sequence(:lname) { |n| "lname#{n}" }
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@google.com" }
  f.password               "password"
  f.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  f.invitation_code        "xxxxxxx"
  f.email_signature_to_extract        ""
end
```

Comment: Whatever `@user1` is does not have such a method, which could be for various reasons. More context is needed.

Comment: Ah crap. I had to run rake spec to rebuild the DB as the field was just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you are calling the method on the User class. In the second you are calling it on a User instance. To fix the second example use:

```
User.stuff_to_extract = 'XXXXXX'
```

or redefine your function to be available to the instance:

```
class User
  def stuff_to_extract= stuff
    ...
  end
end
```

instead of being available to the class:

```
class User
  def self.stuff_to_extract= stuff
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm confused. If the user has several fields like name, lastname, stuff_to_extract. Can't I just do User.stuff_to_extract = xxx

Comment: If the ActiveRecord object has a field in the database named stuff_to_extract, then you can do user = User.new; user.stuff_to_extract = "xxx". But if your first code sample works, namely User.stuff_to_extract = 'xxx', then my guess is you haven't defined the database fields properly and you have defined a class method named 'stuff_to_extract='.

Comment: P.S: You don't need to define the method stuff_to_extract= if you have setup an attribute/database column named stuff_to_extract on the users table and you are using ActiveRecord.